# the process of field's initialization in java

Tags: java, constructor

please how does the Object's no-args constructor initialize the fields of all classes to default values?

```
public class A {

    int x;
    double y;

    A(int x,double y){
        super();
        System.out.println(""+this.x+"  "+this.y+"");
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        System.out.println(""+this.x+"  "+this.y+"");

    }

}
```

once the constructor called new A(2,3); it calls the object's no args constructor which initialize x to 0 and y to 0.0 .

So how it does this initialization?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are calling `super()` with no arguments and therefore it is being set to the default values: 0 for int and 0.0 for double. What is the `super()` btw? What happens if you take that out?

Comment: According to Java VM Spec http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#15858, each instance variable is initialized with a default value when it is created. The default values: 0 for int, 0.0 for double.

Comment: I don't understand your question. And I don't see any problems. If you add a main function that only calls `new A(2, 3)` it will output `0  0.0` and then `2  3.0`. I tried it.

Comment: Default values for primitive types are about half-way down the page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: my question is:  how does the default constructor of the Class Object initialize the fields of all classes to default values?

Answer (score 1):

Its JVM that initialize instance variables to default values. class    `Object`  doesnt hold that responsibility